# Inject local variables into rails partial

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I want my partial below to get the `classy` class from it being injected through locals, but I keep getting undefined method for classy.

//view

```
<%= render layout: "layouts/partial", locals: {className: "classy"} do %>
...
<% end>
```

//partial

```
<div class="regular-div <%=className if className?%>"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean?  You are passing the local variable `className` and also referencing `className`. Are you sure this is not just a typo or sloppy error?

Comment: `className` is not getting into the partial as "classy". I want my div to get the class "classy"

Comment: It should be `<%= className if local_assigns.has_key?(:className)  %>`. Since `className` and `className?` are not the same. `local_assigns.has_key?(:className)` is a way of safely checking if the local variable is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a local variable is set use `local_assigns.has_key?(:some_key)` or `local_assigns[:some_key]` to safely access the local variable.

A nifty way of handling the common task of building a list of classes is:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  # Takes an array or list of classes and returns a string
  # Example:
  #  class_list('a', 'b', nil, 'c')
  #  => "a b"
  #  class_list(['a', 'b', nil, 'c'])
  #  => "a b c"
  def class_list(*classes)
    [*classes].flatten.compact.join(' ') 
  end
end
```

Then you can do:

```
<div class="<%= class_list('regular-div', local_assigns[:className]) %>"></div>
```